# how to hide headers that match regex nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have these config

```
    proxy_hide_header CF-Cache-Status;
    proxy_hide_header CF-RAY;
    proxy_hide_header cf-request-id;
```

How can I proxy hide any header that matches `/^cf-/` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great module for that:

[github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_headers)

From the README

> The wildcard character, *, can also be used at the end of the header name to specify a pattern. For example, the following directive effectively clears any output headers starting by "X-Hidden-":
>
> ```
> more_clear_headers 'X-Hidden-*';
> ```